# Still getting Nativescript splash screen instead of mine

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm developing an iOS app but I'm still getting the Nativescript splash screen even though I did the following:

1. Changed all images in `Assets.xcassets` folder
2. Removed iOS platform using`tns platform remove ios` and added it again (Just in case there was some caching)
3. Deleted the app from my iPhone several times

But still I'm getting the same default Nativescript image when the app is launched on my device! However iOS simulator doesn't have this problem and shows me the new image.

Using tns version 3.2.0:

`"tns-android": {
      "version": "3.2.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.2.0"
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the default Nativescript image only after changing my app id

Answer (score 2):

This is an iOS problem really - after taking the steps you described, you need to... wait for it... reboot the device!

Comment: Thanks Eddy. Just got rid of it after changing my app id!

Comment: Indeed this is a bug logged here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3159